# Manejo de arrays generados en funciones de Wordpress en PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy aprendiendo wordpress y hay una funcion que es `get_the_category()` que te devuelve un array numerico [clave->clave->valor].

El valor de la primera clave es otro array. Esta funcion te devuelve en la primera clave, un valor numerico a la categoria y en el array de dentro muestra informacion de la categoria con su valor. Por ejemplo, id, titulo de categoria, descripcion,etc.

En mi pagina al haber dos categorias, me devuelve este array cuando ejecuto

```html
<html>
    <pre>
<?php print_r(get_the_category());?>
</pre>
</html>
```

El resultado es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que necesito contar esas dos categorias (el 0 y el 1) en PHP

Comment: ¿Contar que de esos registros? ¿que campos?

Comment: ¿O te refieres a un `echo count(get_the_category())`? ¿Y que te diga que hay **2**?

Comment: Me refiero a un codigo php que te devuelva el valor 2 (porque son dos categorias. Hay dos claves: 0 y 1). Y con ese 2 generar un frase tipo: echo "Tienes 2 categorias en esta pagina"

Comment: Pues prueba con lo que he escrito en mi anterior comentario, con el `count()`. Deberia funcionarte tal cual, sino me lo dices y lo mejoramos.